# Importing Node.js npm modules (node_modules) & declarations in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I think it would be great to directly import modules from node_modules directory without need to manually provide a declaration file for it (let us assume that declaration is provided with module itself). I guess that problem are dependencies that come with declarations (file paths could be resolved relative to the module, but that would cause duplicates and compiler can't handle that). 
Currently working with node modules is very inconvenient because simple install from npm repository just isn't enough and we have to manually search for declarations and provide them in our project. Let's say that our project is dependent on 10 node modules (all of them have declarations) and after a year we would like to update them. We would have to manually search for new declarations and let's say that we have around 20 projects like this (it would become a nightmare). Maybe there should be an option to directly import .ts file from node module?

Do you have any suggestions?

This is a re-post from CodePlex to hear your opinions ...

Comment: A link to the codeplex thread would be nice. PS: Don't really get what you're asking a solution for here

Comment: Here is a link to the CodePlex thread ...
https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/440670

Answer (score 2):

If you use grunt-typescript then I've got a pull request which solves this at least for me. See https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript/pull/36

From the pull request README

## Working with modules in node_modules (i.e. npm)

The standard way to use npm packages is to provide a definition file
that specifies the package to the typescript and import the module from there.

```
///<reference path="path/to/mod.d.ts" />
import mod = module('mod')
```

The typescript compiler will convert the `import` to a nodejs `require`.

```
var mod = require('mod')
```

This is pretty unwieldy as you need to know the precise path to the
npm installed package and npm can put the package at pretty much any
level when you are working with multiple levels of dependencies.

With the `node_modules` option in the grunt config you can just
`import` a npm package without need to know the exact level where the
package has been installed by npm as long as it is installed locally
and not globally.

To `import` an npm module in your typescript source do

```
import npmModule = module('node_modules/npmModule/foo')
```

Mostly due to a lucky chance this works. Typescript compiler will read
the typescript definition file `node_modules/npmModule/foo.d.ts` if it
is present at some point on the way towards the root and the resulting
javascript file will contain a `require` for `npmModule/foo` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that node modules will ever contain built-in typescript support. The language still is a 0.x release and officially described as an alpha version.

Nevertheless there are means to ease the configuration process for typescript. Github already contains huge collections of .d.ts files such as:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped
or
https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions

You might want to take a look at this tool: https://github.com/Diullei/tsd .
I've never used it but it seems like it's almost what you're looking for.

Moreover I've heard that an official database of .d.ts files is planned. Unfortunately I couldn't find the link but it will probably be some time before this is implemented anyways.

Comment: TSD is looking nice and might just be what we need ... Somehow it would be gread it declarations could be resolved from node_modules folder.